# Elegant way to return json field if field is null in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask

I've a dumb question about my flask REST API. If i have a user model with a lot of information and i want to return it as json. But some of the information is still don't have any value (NULL). What's the elegant way to return it as a empty string or another default value instead of returning it as null.

Something like this:

```
{ 
  'username': 'foo',
  'fullname' : ''
}
```

instead of this:

```
{ 
  'username': 'foo',
  'fullname' : null
}
```

This is my function:

```
def json(self):
        return {
            'username': self.phone,
            'fullname': self.fullname
        }
```

This is the user model:

```
class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80))
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

Comment: can you post your nominal User model structure (definition)?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i've edited my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sqlalchemy.schema.Column`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) class allows specifying `default=` parameter:

```
class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80))
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(80), default="")
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default

Comment: @ikhsan I think you would want to set it to not-nullable otherwise `None` values may still present if assigned after initialization, and they will still be served by the API.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have conditions in your return dict:

```
def json(self):
        return {
            'username': self.phone if self.phone else '',
            'fullname': self.fullname if self.fullname else ''
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want to override `None` value in Python, you can use `or` operator like this:

```
def json(self):
    return {
        'username': self.phone,
        'fullname': self.fullname or 'some default value'
    }
```

In case `self.fullname` has a value, it will be returned. But if it's `None`, then `'some default value'` comes up.

Hope that helps.